# Firestore nested collections schema refactoring

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

We are considering the schema design of our firestore db and are interested in using subcollections to organise the data. Say we have data that models ships, their voyages and logs they have to keep. We could model this with nested collections sort of like this:

```
// {} signifies a collection

{Ships}
  001
  {Voyages}
    voy1
    {Logs}
      12:01 This was all good
      12:11 Things are still good
    voy2
    {Logs}
      09:00 Setting sail
      13:00 Iceberg, dead ahead
  002
  {Voyages}
    voy3
    {Logs}
      16:00 Ship 002 is lost
```

This is quite nice because it allows to stuff like this:

```
// get all the voyages for ship 001
db.doc('Ships/001');

// get info and logs for voyage 1
db.doc('Ships/001/Voyage/voy1');

// get all the Logs across all voyages
collectionGroup('Logs');
```

And all the other nice things we can do with nested collections...

The nested collections help us describe the relationships between each of these entities and easily pick out the related data without having to do any joins in the client-side.

**However**, my question is what happens if we identify down-the-line that the relationships in our schema are not correct? For example, we find that Logs are not necessarily related to the voyage because the ships will even take logs when not on a voyage? Or that Ships can be grouped into fleets - a level above Ships. Do we have to migrate our schema? Do we have to hybrid our relations by joining in client code and relying on nested structure?

Comment: Would you like me to provide an answer with another idea of such a structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both potential changes could be handled by not nesting the documents. Consider instead a set of root level collections like this...

```
Fleets
  fleet0: {}

Ships
  ship0: { fleet: ref-to-a-fleet } // problem 2. no migration,
                                   // just add a fleet "foreign key"
  ...

Voyages
  voyage0: { ship: ref-to-a-ship }
  ...

Logs
  log0: { voyage: ref-to-a-voyage }
  log1: { ship: ref-to-a-ship }      // problem 1. "foreign key" can be to any
                                     // other collection
```

This changes your query pattern a little bit, but in a durable way.  It's a nice feature of your current setup that the collection can be described by a path, but (since firestore provides indexes) it's a little less pretty, but roughly as efficient to do this...

```
// original design
db.doc('Ships/001');

// new design
let ship = db.doc('Ships/001');
db.collection('voyages').where('ship', '==', ship);
```

Both refs can then be sent a `get()` to get the same querySnapshot.

EDIT:

[Here's a video that discusses pros/cons](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/concepts/structure-data).  I would characterize the conclusion as ambiguous.  It points out:

1. as I did, that the qualified query on the top-level (`where id ==`) is about as fast as query all in the nested collection
2. that the top-level organization allow one to query things that span multiple parents (this could be very important for you: what if you want all voyages made to a certain port, no matter the ship?).
3. on the other hand: in my suggestion, if you want sorted results in any query, you'll have to create a composite index (easy, but an extra dev step).
4. also, on the other hand, it might be tougher to write security rules top-level collections, like when the rule depends on data in the parent (though `get`s are possible, too, in security rules)

On the whole, though, since main concern is future flexibility, I think I've demonstrated that the top-level collection provides a better solution.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So, to me, there doesn't seem to be too much of an advantage of using nested collections currently, especially with the limits in flexibility shown

Comment: Yes.  I think that's right.  I thought I saw a doc somewhere in the firestore guides that agrees, also, but I can't seem to find it now.